# buttons in flex box have small margin even when set to fill available space

Tags: css, flexbox

I am building a footer for a mobile device.  The footer should have 3 buttons with no space between.

The container is styled like this

```
.NavBar {
    width: 100vw;
    float: none;
    display: flex;
    height: 3rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

and the buttons are styled like this

```
.NavButton {
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #dddddd;
    /* border: 1px solid black; */
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    /* float: left; */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin: none;
    font-family: Montserrat-Regular, Geneva
}
```

Since I have `flex-grow: 1` on each button shouldn't they grow to fill the full screen width.

I end up with about 1 px of padding between each button.

Comment: Could you make the code a snippet since I don't have immediate editing rights?

Comment: You're missing a semi-colon on font-family by the way

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce my issue but if you visit https://boiling-fortress-12202.herokuapp.com/#/ on a mobile device you can see the issue in the footer

Comment: I don't see the problem (iOS 14, iPhone 7, Firefox and Safari). They are the same color so I can't tell. Maybe add a temporary border so it is easy to tell? Or just not care at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you mean you have 1px margin between each button, not a padding.

There is no such thing as `margin:none;`, try replacing that with `margin:0;` or `margin:0px !important`. This is very likely to fix your issue.

If that doesnt work (but it should), try using the asterix (*) on the start of your css, to reset padding and margin of all elements on a page.

Like this :

```
*{

margin: 0px;
padding : 0px;

}
```

Let me know if it worked ! :)

Comment: It's still there :(

Comment: Is this what you are trying to achieve ? :)

https://codepen.io/Juka99/pen/XWjMyJM